# How to disable blinking action on hovering - CSS3

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I'd like to disable any action that runs when hovering over a state. I want to start blinking when I load my chart, but I don't want to run blinking again from the beggining when I hover over a state.

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7cogkzjt/

```
.blinking-points {
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-name: blinking;
    animation-iteration-count: 10;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes blinking {
    0% {
        fill: red;
    }
    50% {
        fill: yellow;
    }
    100% {
        fill: blue;
    }
}
```

I tried to delete classes after 5000 miliseconds, but blinking runs again from beggining when I hover before 5 seconds pass, and blinking on all states are not synchronized.

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/15Lrqhf9/

```
chart: {
      events: {
        load() {
          var chart = this;
          setTimeout(function() {
            $.each(data, function() {
              if (i % 2 == 0)
                this['className'] = '';
              else
                this['className'] = '';
              i++;
            });
            chart.series[0].update({
              data: data
            })
          }, 5000)
        }
      }
    },
```

I just want to run blinking only once when I load my chart and DON'T run it again after hovering. So hovering doesn't affect anything - doesn't turn off blinking and doesn't run blinking again. Thanks!

Comment: I did not see any animation play when I hovered over a 'state', however would [`animation-play-state`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state) CSS property help you on hover?

Comment: When you hover over USA state, animation (blinking) starts from the beggining (and lasts longer than the animation which starts when you load a page).
animation-play-state with paused, running and unset doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set on init `plotOptions.series.enableMouseTracking` equal to false to avoid adding `hover` state to the points. Then, you can use `setTimeout` function set on `chart.events.load` function to toggle class `blinking-points` on your points and finally, enable mouse tracking again by setting it to `true`. Here is the code and live example:

```
chart: {
  map: 'countries/us/us-all',
  borderWidth: 1,
  events: {
    load() {
      var chart = this
      setTimeout(function() {
        var points = chart.series[0].points

        // Toggle class 'blinking-points' to avoid starting animation twice
        points.forEach(p => {
          p.update({
            className: ''
          })
        })

        // Enable mouse tracking to make tooltip available again
        chart.update({
          plotOptions: {
            series: {
              enableMouseTracking: true,
            }
          },
        })

      }, 5000)
    }
  }
},
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    enableMouseTracking: false,
  }
}
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/p80aj5sb/

Kind regards!

Comment: You are gorgeous, daniel_s!!! This is exactly what I've been looking for ;) AMAZING

Answer (score 0):

Try using javaScript **setTimeout** function as shown below:

```
$.getJSON('https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/057b672172ccc6c08fe7dbb27fc17ebca3f5b770/samples/data/us-population-density.json', function (data) {

    let i = 0;
    // Make codes uppercase to match the map data
    $.each(data, function () {
        this.code = this.code.toUpperCase();
        if(i%2 == 0)
        this['className'] = 'blinking-points';
        else 
        this['className'] = '';
        i++;

    });

    // Instantiate the map
    Highcharts.mapChart('container', {

        chart: {
            map: 'countries/us/us-all',
            borderWidth: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'US population density (/km²)'
        },

        exporting: {
            sourceWidth: 600,
            sourceHeight: 500
        },

        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.85)',
            floating: true,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25
        },

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true
        },

        colorAxis: {
            min: 1,
            type: 'logarithmic',
            minColor: '#EEEEFF',
            maxColor: '#000022',
            stops: [
                [0, '#EFEFFF'],
                [0.67, '#4444FF'],
                [1, '#000022']
            ]
        },

        series: [{
            animation: {
                duration: 1000
            },
            data: data,
            joinBy: ['postal-code', 'code'],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                format: '{point.code}'
            },

            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },

            name: 'Population density',
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{point.code}: {point.value}/km²'
            }
        }]
    });

   //Add this code
window.setTimeout(function(){
     $('.blinking-points').removeClass('blinking-points');
   },5000);
});
```

You can use timer then and set the delay equal to time interval for which you want to keep the states blinking. Here 5000 delay equals to 5 sec so after 5 sec, the callback function will be invoked automatically and remove the **blinking-points** class and hence the states will stop blinking for ever.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the will, but I don't want to stop blinking when hovering. I want nothing to change when hovering. I just want this blinking when chart is loaded. I don't want to run blinking again and I don't want that hovering affects on it.

Comment: Try the updated answer using the javaScript setTimeout function

Comment: I have tried this already (like I described in my question). The class is removed after 5 seconds, but before 5 seconds pass hovering changes animations and there are different colors over the 'USA states" (not synchronized) - like i said in question. But still thanks for a try